# Alternate tr color of not yet existing table in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I know the question sounds weird, but here's the thing:
When someone press a button on my webpage, a new tr is created.
After the tr is created I want to alternate the tr colors on my table, so I use this code:
but this doesn't work.

```
$("table.content_table_fill tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
$("table.content_table_fill tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
```

For some reason this doesn't work.
Help please.

Comment: please share you code

Answer (score 0):

if you have to doit your way, then just call this again on button click:

```
$("your_button_clicked_on_the_website").click(function(){
    //adding tr's n stuff
    $("table.content_table_fill tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
    $("table.content_table_fill tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1"); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you just need to put your styles into a CSS style sheet, not try to add them as inline styles.  They'll then automatically apply to any new rows created.

If for some reason you don't want the table to be styled until *after* the button has been pressed, use an extra class on the table itself that you would refer to in the style sheet, and that only gets added by the button click event handler, e.g. in your style sheet put this:

```
table.content_table_fill.alternated tr:even { background-color: #F4F4F8; }
table.content_table_fill.alternated tr:odd { background-color: #EFF1F1; }
```

and in your code put this:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
     $('.content_table_fill').addClass('alternated');
});
```